# How can I get the text from div by name with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to display the content from a `DIV` name as `sample`.
Below the code I am trying, But it will return empty result.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div name="sample" >This is sample text</div>
<button id="getText" >Get External Content</button>
```

**SCRIPT CODE:**

```
$("#getText").click(function(){     
        var sample = $('div[name=sample]').val(); 
        console.log("sample="+sample); //Empty result   
});
```

**Expecting Result:**

sample=This is sample text

Thanks to all!

Comment: Sorry to all. I am forgot the `.text()` in JQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A div is a div, it has no value, thus `.val()` is returning nothing.

Either change it to an input, or use `.html()` or `.text()`

Comment: Thanks, I am forgot the `.text()` in JQuery

Answer (score 1):

Use `.text()` instead:

```
$('div[name=sample]').text();
```

`.val()` jQuery method is used to get the values form the `form` elements such as `input, select, radio, checkbox` etc.

You have to use `.text()` to get the `textContent` of the `div` element.

Comment: Thanks, I am forgot the `.text()` in JQuery